# How does one calculate the decay width of an a1 Meson into a $\pi$ and a $\rho$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model, mesons

I'm trying to make a theoretical prediction of the decay width (and by extension lifetime) of an a1 Meson into a rho⁰ and a pi⁻ (the rho⁰ then decays into a pi⁺⁻ pair). I can't seem to find the necessary propagators and vertexes to calculate $\mathcal{M}$, and using $\mathcal{M}$ then calculate $d\Gamma$ and then finally $\Gamma$ which is the approach ive used up to now. Does anyone know any resources (papers) I could use, or any other tips?

Edit: thanks to Cosmos for pointing out that this is strong decay. Can the CKM Matrix be used here? And if yes, how?

Comment: It is a plain [strong decay](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2014/listings/rpp2014-list-a1-1260.pdf). The refs in the PDG might review expectations. What propagators are you talking about? How did you compute $\rho\to \pi \pi$?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I havent computed $\rho \rightarrow \pi \pi$ yet, just $\Gamma_\tau$ using the Muon to electron decay. Could I theoretically just use the CKM Matrix since its just meson to meson decay?

Comment: Hadronic strong reactions involve phenomenological amplitudes, much unlike  the weak decays you considered. I'm not sure where to get you started... the phase space calculations are the same, but the matrix elements are often given, not calculated.

Comment: Lattice QCD has been used to model strong interactions. see https://arxiv.org/abs/0708.3705 or https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-lat/0606005

Comment: Thank you @CosmasZachos and anna v . I think im on the right track now.

Comment: Since you are not dealing with valence quarks, or weak interactions, the CKM matrix is strictly irrelevant.